# How to plot .tif file colour coding onto the map using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, geotiff-tiff, plot, react

I want to plot color coding from the .tif file into the map with the help of react-leaflet. How can this be done?

I am open to other better suggestions. My core goal is to display color coding given in the GeoTIFF file on an interactive map dynamically on a website.